# Serenity BDD doesn't take screenshots with appium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, browser-automation, serenity-bdd

I have a problem with Serenity BDD using the Screenplay Pattern with appium (I'm using Appium 1.3.1), the project do not generate the Screenshots in each Step, the generated report doesn't show the capture of the step, but in my code i don't have any issue or error in the IDE, this is my code and the capture of the Serenity Report:

```
import net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.abilities.BrowseTheWeb;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.questions.page.TheWebPage;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Issue;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Managed;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Screenshots;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Steps;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.findby.By;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import com.Otherpackage.tasks.OpenTheApplication;
import com.Otherpackage.tasks.Search;
import com.Otherpackage.tasks.escribeNombre;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import static net.serenitybdd.screenplay.GivenWhenThen.*;
import static net.serenitybdd.screenplay.EventualConsequence.eventually;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
public class SearchByKeywordStory {


Actor anna = Actor.named("Anna");

@Managed
public static AppiumDriver<WebElement> herBrowser;

@Steps
OpenTheApplication openTheApplication;

@Before
public void annaCanBrowseTheWeb() {
    anna.can(BrowseTheWeb.with(herBrowser));
}

@Test
public void search_results_should_show_the_search_term_in_the_title() throws 
MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    String packagename = "com.facebook.katana";
    String URL="http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";
    String activityname = "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity";
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy S5");
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", "284596bb");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", packagename);
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", activityname);
    capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);

    herBrowser= new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(URL), capabilities);
    herBrowser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        

    Thread.sleep(4000);             
    when(anna).attemptsTo(escribeNombre.yacasi());

}


}
```

this is the other class "escribeNombre" that contain the Step:

```
package com.Otherpackage.tasks;

import static net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Tasks.instrumented;
import static org.openqa.selenium.Keys.ENTER;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import com.accenture.features.search.SearchByKeywordStory;
import com.accenture.ui.SearchBox;

import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Task;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.actions.Click;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.actions.Enter;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Step;

public class escribeNombre implements Task {

@Step("Abre la App y busca nombre")
public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {
    WebElement num3 =  

SearchByKeywordStory.herBrowser.findElementByClassName
("android.widget.EditText");    //Click a la barra de busqueda.      
    num3.sendKeys("Daniel Correa \n"); 



}    
   public static escribeNombre yacasi() {
       return instrumented(escribeNombre.class);
   }

}
```

and this is the Serenity Report, doesn't take any screenshot in the steps
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GSVO.png

anyone can help me with this? in the webpage it have little documentation about using it with appium, http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_running_tests_on_appium

if you have and example with serenity with appium would be great help for me

thanks for reading and sorry for my hardcoded code

Answer (score -1):

Can you try setting serenity.take.screenshots=AFTER_EACH_STEP in serenity.properties file.

You can follow this thread about [screenshots are not found in the serenity report](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber-starter/issues/2).

This gives idea about getting screenshots on reports.